# ld: truncated fat file for manual added framework

Tags: swift, xcode8

Having an issue with a manual added framework. I was working before when I added this manual but with changes I have done I'm getting now.

```
ld: truncated fat file. Slice from 2670592 to 5510224 is past end of file with length 5505024 file '.....' for architecture x86_64
```

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I don't have any idea how to sort it. Working now with XCode Version 8.3.2 (8E2002).

Answer (score 0):

```
Try to made following changes in your project:-

    Include all necessary frameworks in the link phase
    Remove -all_load from Other Linker Flags.
    Clean the build folder and re-compiled from scratch.

This could very well be a permission issue, a corrupt iOS SDK install, or a corrupt Xcode install. I would remove /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulatorXXX.sdk, then go into Xcode > Preferences > Downloads and reinstall the iOS SDK. Then try again to clean and build your project. If you still have problems, I would consider reinstalling Xcode again.
```